# How to open Paypal in inApp Browser using cordova/phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-cli

I am integrating PayPal integration using JavaScript in PhoneGap, but I'm facing an issue that it is not opening in the inApp browser. Instead of that it is opening outside of my app. So I want the PayPal URL to be opened in the inApp browser.
I'm new to PhoneGap so if anyone knows please help with it. Below is the code

```
<form id="openpaypal" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="NSH74TD463ZSU">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer,  easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>

//script here

<script>
        document.getElementById("openpaypal").addEventListener("click", openBrowser);

        function openBrowser() {
            alert("called here");
            var url = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
            var target = '_blank';
            var options = "location=yes"
            var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, target, options);

            ref.addEventListener('loadstart', loadstartCallback);
            ref.addEventListener('loadstop', loadstopCallback);
            ref.addEventListener('loadloaderror', loaderrorCallback);
            ref.addEventListener('exit', exitCallback);

            function loadstartCallback(event) {
                console.log('Loading started: ' + event.url)
            }

            function loadstopCallback(event) {
                console.log('Loading finished: ' + event.url)
            }

            function loaderrorCallback(error) {
                console.log('Loading error: ' + error.message)
            }

            function exitCallback() {
                console.log('Browser is closed...')
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Yes its because of your first line, just add your `cordova.js` without any folder path like `<script src="cordova.js" type="text/javascript></script>`

Comment: These are scripts added for phonegap

<script src="assets/js/cordova.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/js/min/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: I have added already but still it's not open in inApp Browser

Comment: Are you sure you have removed folder path from it ?

Comment: yes I removed.. I din't given any folder path for it

Comment: <script src="cordova.js" type="text/javascript"></script> i added

Comment: And plugin also installed successfully for inappbrowser ?

Comment: yes this is the inApp browser plugin I have added cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser ..but still its not resolved

Comment: I edited my answer please have a look once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## For cordova command

**Add Plugin First**

[Here](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova/inappbrowser/inappbrowser.html) is link

```
$ cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git
```

This is your script

```
<script src="assets/js/cordova.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="assets/js/min/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But while building an app `cordova.js` automatically add to root path of www folder

**So add it like below**

```
<script src="cordova.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

## For PhoneGap Build

add this line to config.xml file

```
<plugin name="org.li8.inappbrowser" spec="0.1" source="pgb" />
```

Set Script

```
<script src="phonegap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

## Edited

call your function after device ready may be it is making problem for you

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

function onDeviceReady()
{
    document.getElementById("openpaypal").addEventListener("click", openBrowser);
}

function openBrowser() 
{
    var url = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
    var target = '_blank';
    var options = "location=yes";
    var ref = window.open(url, target, options);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for yours info. I will check it

Comment: Anyhow Thank you. I have found alternative solution for it using javascript.

Comment: @ShivanandL.C Can you post the details how you figured it out. I am looking for similar code.